# ChildNode.remove() polyfill with babel-polyfill

Tags: javascript, babeljs, polyfills, babel-polyfill

I am using [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) and I described by Mozilla I need a polyfill for IE. I am using webpack with the babel-polyfill configured:

```
 "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
 "webpack": "^2.4.1",
```

**webpack.config.babel.js:**

```
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', join(__dirname, path, "index.web.js") ],
```

My assumption was that **babel-polyfill** would provide me all the common polyfill I needed - but it is not, I have an error in **Internet Explorer 11**. Is there another config I missed?

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `babel-polyfill` packages just polyfills javascript objects as far as I know, `Childnode.remove()` is part of the DOM so babel won't do anything with it. I would suggest that you just use the polyfill suggested in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).

```
// from:https://github.com/jserz/js_piece/blob/master/DOM/ChildNode/remove()/remove().md
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function remove() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, CharacterData.prototype, DocumentType.prototype]);
```

Comment: Both CharacterData and DocumentType have some compatibility issues themselves, so use those extra polyfills with caution

Comment: How exactly do you implement this? You just paste the function at the end of your script?

Comment: Polyfills must be registered before they can be used so it should go at the beginning rather then the end.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to (or in addition to) the babel-polyfill, you can look at [Polyfill.io](https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/docs/).

Like `babel-polyfill`, Polyfill.io will provide core Javascript functionality (e.g. `Array.from`), but unlike babel-polyfill, it also polyfills DOM behavior, (e.g. `ChildNode.remove()`).  By default, it uses the browser user-agent string to determine which polyfills are necessary, preventing modern browsers from needing to download polyfills they don't need.

The main thing that Polyfill.io doesn't provide, which `babel-polyfill` does, is support for generator functions (provided by regenerator-runtime), so for full functionality, you'd want to include that instead of the whole `babel-polyfill`.

Answer (score 3):

I created a tiny polyfill npm.
Should make you life easier.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-remove